# How to edit contact form 7 'send-to' address on specific post types? - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields, contact-form-7

---

I'm developing a realty website with which I'm using these plugins:

Contact Form 7

Advanced Custom Fields

---

Every Contact Form 7 Form has to send an email to the Agent selling the property listed on the page.

I'm currently printing the contact form to the page using the wpcf7 shortcode.

```
    $prep = '[contact-form-7 id="4" title="Property-Agent-CF"]';

    echo do_shortcode($prep); 
?>
```

I also created a hook that (from my knowledge) should accept the existing wpcf7 object on the loaded singular post page.. and edit the email to be the email of the agent selected.

```
function fsd_properties_wpcf7( &$WPCF7 ) {
    if ( $WPCF7->posted_data['_wpcf7_unit_tag'] == 'wpcf7-f4-p451-o1' ) {
        $agent_email = get_field('agent_email');
        $WPCF7->mail['recipient'] = $agent_email;
    } else {
        $WPCF7->mail['recipient'] = "Juan <juan@wordpress.com>";
    }
}
add_action("wpcf7_contact_form", "fsd_properties_wpcf7");
```

I'm not sure how to grab the existing WPCF7 Object associated to the form on the page with this hook.